# In a commutative algebraic theory, do all constant symbols necessarily represent the same value?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $T$ denote a [commutative algebraic theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory) with two nullary function symbols $a$ and $b$ (i.e. constants). Is it an automatic consequence of the definitions that $a=b$ is a theorem of $T$?

*My thoughts.* I think the answer is **yes**, simply by "following the pattern." In particular, let $a()$ represent a nullary function. Then we have the following.

- Suppose $f(*,*)$ represents a binary function. Then I think it is a consequence of the definitions that $f(a(),a()) = a()$ in every interpertation.
- Similarly, if $f(*)$ represents a unary function, then I think that $f(a()) = a()$ in every interpretation.
- Taking the pattern to its logical conclusion, I think that if $f()$ is a nullary function, then $f()=a()$ in every interpertation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of "$a$ and $b$ commute", you start with the $0\times 0$ matrix (in effect "nothing"), apply $a$ to "each" row (as there are no rows, you do nothing), then apply $b$ to the ($0$ size) row of results and obtain $b()$. In the other order you obtain $a()$ and commutativity thus states that $b()=a()$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

That two constants i.e. 0-ary operations commute with each other says exactly that they are equal, by definition. You don't need any "logic" or higher-ary operations in order to see this. Details:

Recall that that two maps $t : A^n \to A$ and $t' : A^m \to A$ *commute* if for all $x=(x_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq n,~ 1 \leq j \leq m} \in A^{n \times m}$ we have 
$$t(t'(x_{11},\dotsc,x_{1m}),\dotsc,t'(x_{n1},\dotsc,x_{nm}))
 = t'(t(x_{11},\dotsc,x_{n1}),\dotsc,t(x_{1m},\dotsc,x_{nm})).$$
This has a nice visualization through matrices, see the nlab article.

For $n=0$ we have $A^n=\{\star\}$, the set with only one element (which we denote always by $\star$ for all $n$). Hence $t,t'$ correspond to constants $t(\star),t'(\star)$, and $\star$ is the only possible input for $t$ and $t'$. Hence, commutativity reduces to
$$t = t'.$$

Comment: Therein lies the problem; its not clear to me how to unpack the definitions to arrive at the conclusion that if two constants commute, then they're equal (or rather, represent equal quantities). Thoughts?

Comment: I've added details.